# pytest does not see the webdriver from the different file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I have a simple code setup_test.py that perfectly works in the common package

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = None

def setup_function():
    print("Setup")
    global driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
    driver.maximize_window()

def teardown_function():
    print("Teardown")
    if driver:
        driver.quit()

def test_me1():
    driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
    print("Inside t1")
    time.sleep(3)

def test_me2():
    driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
    print("Inside t2")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Then I moved the following part to the file pre_test.py in the same package

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = None

def setup_function():
    print("Setup")
    global driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
    driver.maximize_window()

def teardown_function():
    print("Teardown")
    if driver:
        driver.quit()
```

Now the test file contains only

```
from .pre_test import driver

def test_me1():
    driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
    print("Inside t1")
    time.sleep(3)

def test_me2():
    driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
    print("Inside t2")
    time.sleep(3)
```

However, when I run it, I get error message

def test_me1():

> ```
>   driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
> ```

E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

setup_test.py:27: AttributeError

that indicates that setup_test.py does not see the driver, which is None.

Please, help. What is wrong?

Comment: You need to move your setup functions to `conftest.py` to be found. I would also make them `autouse` fixtures, which is the more common way and avoids the need for separate functions for setup and teardown, or fixtures that yield the driver instead of making it global.

Comment: I do not want to use fixtures. I moved the setup_function and tear_down function to the conftest.py, and still have the same error: driver = None.  Maybe it should be a different import statement.

Comment: Ah ok, this simply won't work with `setup_function` in another module. If you don't want to use fixtures (what is even the point of using pytest then?) you have to define it in the same module, as you did, otherwise it won't be called. And yes, your import wouldn't have worked either, because you are essentially making a copy of `driver` in your module. You need to import the module instead (or better avoid globals).

Comment: MrBean, just your opinion. Why in all books on Selenium/Pytest all tests are initially created without classes? Why not to start all tests as class methods from the get-go?

Comment: I'm not discussing that. I was just wondering (as a side note) why you are using pytest at all, which uses fixtures as its main feature. But that's your choice.